# Why there's nothing display?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to Three.js, so I might have made some stupid mistakes. This is my code, and I want to build a geometry using coordinates and surface information from a .k file. I've tried printing geometry.vertices and geometry.faces, and they both look correct, I also tried changing the camera position, but nothing has shown on the screen. Help, please!

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var map = {}; // node id map to index geometry vertices

// reading in k file line by line
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var node_flag = false, element_flag = false;

    reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
        var lines = this.result.split('\n');
        for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; ++line){
            if(!node_flag && lines[line].substr(0,5) == "*NODE") {
                node_flag = true;
                continue;
            }
            if(lines[line].substr(0,8) == "$# title")
                node_flag = false;
            else if(lines[line].substr(0,14) == "*ELEMENT_SHELL") {
                element_flag = true;
                continue;
            }
            else if(lines[line].substr(0,14) == "*ELEMENT_SOLID")
                break;
            // start reading nodes and build vectors
            if(node_flag) {
                // tokenize a line into array of strings
                let data = lines[line].match(/\S+/g);
                map[data[0]] = geometry.vertices.length-1;
                geometry.vertices.push((new THREE.Vector3(+data[1], +data[2], +data[3])));
            }
            // start reading element shell and building surfaces
            if(element_flag){
                // tokenize a line into array of strings
                let data = lines[line].match(/\S+/g);
                geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(map[data[2]], map[data[3]],map[data[4]]));
                // geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(map[data[2]]), map[data[5]],map[data[4]]);
            }
        }
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
    finish_loading();
}

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
var cube;

// test
var axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 5 );
scene.add( axesHelper );
//test

camera.position.z = 100;


function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

       cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
       //cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    // cube.rotation.z += 0.01;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}


function finish_loading(){
    cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );
    animate();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>MDP Web-tool</title>
    <!--js library-->
    <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src = "js/library/three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/library/node_modules/hashmap/hashmap.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id = "myCanvas"></canvas>
    <input type="file" id="file">
    <!--custom js files-->
    <script src="js/model.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What format is a .k file?

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys, .k file is the keyword file stores a geometry's information, such as coordinates of each node and surfaces are consist of which nodes.

Comment: @Craicerjack no error comes out....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `finish_loading()` outside of your `onload` callback. It will get executed in place long before your `.onload` callback fires. Put it after the for loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, still nothing comes out, could that be the geometry is hidden behind the camera? I haven't implemented orbit-control to change perspective

Comment: put a regular three mesh in your scene to test if the problem is in the mesh building. You should also make sure you `camera.lookAt( THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0)  );` and add a light to the scene

Comment: Right, the regular three mesh shows. The problem is solved! it was hidden behind the camera, and i found it by rotation another axis in the animate function. Thanks a lot, really appreciate it!